# HashMap Null when get Element

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I use in DB column Hashmap with type Hstore :

```
@TypeDef(name = "hstore", typeClass = HstoreUserType.class)
  
@Type(type="hstore")
@Column(columnDefinition = "hstore")
private HashMap<String,String> extraInfo;
```

The problem is when I get an element in the table where the Hashmap is null I have a message :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.HstoreUserType.convertToEntityAttribute(HstoreUserType.java:138) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.HstoreUserType.nullSafeGet(HstoreUserType.java:71) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
```

I want to use this column optionnal and when the hashmap is null don't go to HstoreUserType.class in the Type DEF.

Comment: Have you tried assigning a new empty map to this field inside your entity?

Comment: I want to don't assign a Map if there is no data, it's possible ? In Jpa ?

Comment: You mean, is it possible to persist a Map field into a single column in JPA ? Yes, using an `AttributeConverter`, and NOT using some JPA providers vendor extension

Comment: i think treating null as indicator for no data isnt a good approach. An empty list indicating no data seems to be a perfect approach. Overthink your intention and may apply the solution of @NestorSokil

Comment: theres no data in your column